# prop and ctor shortcuts + tab key not working in vscode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Is there an extension I need to install to get prop and ctor shortcuts to work in VSCode the way they do in VS2015? It is not working for me when I type prop + tab

Answer (score 2):

Code snippets are not built into Visual Studio Code - though you can create them yourself, as [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) shows.

Some snippets come with specific extensions - like the [C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp).

Comment: I am pretty sure: C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp) Extension is supposed to come with these snippets...

Comment: @BlakeRivell - in VS Code, trigerring snippets (on Windows) is with Ctrl + space, not with a tab.

Comment: I see this brings up a menu for selection, but no prop or ctor in it. And if I type prop then hit ctrl + space, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an extension I need to install to get prop and ctor shortcuts to work in VSCode the way they do in VS2015?

You need to [install the C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp) to get `prop` and `ctor` shortcuts (aka snippets) to work.

Two caveats:

1. they work slightly differently than they do in VS2015.
2. [a bug in version 1.9.0 of the C# (OmniSharp) extension](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1459) breaks the `ctor` and `prop` snippets.

**We can fix the bug ourselves as follows:**

1. Make sure you have the C# (OmniSharp) extension installed.
2. Then open `~\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.9.0\snippets\csharp.json` in a text editor.
3. Find and replace all tabs with spaces.

After doing that, restart VS Code. All the snippets, including `prop` and `ctor`, will be available.

[image: The prop snippet works.]

Pro tip: If we enter the command pallet and type `snippet`, we can see all the available snippets for the current language. If the last one in your list is `iterindex`, then you have the above bug.

[image: Show all available snippets.]

Answer (score -1):

In VS2019, the Extension "C# Methods Code Snippets" 1.3.1 will give you the "ctor" [tab] constructor snippet functionality.

Comment: The question is about vscode (visual studio code), not vs (visual studio).